# How avoid deformation of mesh after imported it on Unity?

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, unity

On my job, i received a human model on Blender made from another person, i don't know how he created the model but i've a problem when import this with animation on Unity.

In Blender the animation doesn't seem to give problem.

look! All mesh's deformation are clear

[image]

The problem is when export and import on Unity. When I start the animation the model deformed in very strange way

strange deformations appear in the pelvis, under the armpits and on the neck

[image]

I've noticed that the mesh model has applied over four armature modifiers. I'm tried to delete all of this and re-apply newly the armature, but the problem still.

This the four modifier

[image]

This are my exporting setting

[image]

does anyone know what caused the problem? How do I avoid it?

Comment: It's hard to see the problem just by looking at some pics. BUT in your case, the problem might be this --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ibNZbPW2by4.